# Which cvtype to choose for standard 24-bit png image in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am new to image processing and a little bit confused with OpenCV Data Types even though I read the documentation (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html).

Which CVType do I have to choose for a standard 24-bit png image with 3 colors + alpha channel?

Comment: CV_8UC4 (4channels a 8bit). why do you ask ? where's the problematic piece of code ?

Comment: 3 colors + alpha looks like 32 bit instead of 24 bit?!? If you want to LOAD such an image you have to select a special parameter for `imread`, otherwise the image is loaded as (or converted to) 8UC3 image automatically and doesnt care about original depth and nr of channels.

Comment: image SAVING has some limitations, look at the documentation of `cv::imwrite`

Comment: thank you. can you also say why it is 8UC4? because 8*4=32 bit. ah ok, if the alpha channel does not count, it is 24 bit (I asked for 24 bit because in photoshop pngs are typically saved as 8 or 24 bit). but why do you take unsigned short? (that is what the U stands for, right?) as I said, I am quite new to image processing...

Comment: sorry, i was wrong: UC stands for unsigned char and a char is 8 bits. now it makes sense. thank you.

Comment: Number stands for bit-per-channel U stands for unsigned C stands for "channels" and the last number is the number of channels. So 8UC4 is 4 channels with each 8 bit unsigned integer (which is an unsigned char). 16SC1 would be single channel short (16 bit signed) 32FC1 is single channel float, 64FC3 is 3 channels with double precision float values.